# Appending a constant Array in the main app from a Rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, constants, rails-engines

yes, I want to append a CONSTANT,

I have an array that is stored as a constant in the mainapp, something like

```
class FOO
  ABILITY = [["xxxx","XX"],["yy","YYY"]]
end
```

above constant is used throughout the mainapp in various ways.

now, I have a rails engine that extends the mainapps abilities, and would like to extend the ABILITY array in the main app so if I where  to do a

```
ABILITY.each
```

i would get an extra pair.

Without thinking, I just did a

```
class BAR
  FOO::ABILITY << ["zzzz","ZZZZ"]
end
```

of course this didn't do anything.

I have never considered appending a constant, which in its self seems like a bad thing to do, but considering the purpose of the RailsEngine, for it feels like an adequate idea, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
class FOO
  ABILITY = [["xxx","XX"],["yy","yyyy"]]
end

class BAR
  T= FOO::ABILITY << ["zzz","ZZ"]
end

BAR::T
=> [["xxx", "XX"], ["yy", "yyyy"], ["zzz", "ZZ"]]
```

you were missing a "," in your ABILITY array. Does that help?

Comment: sorry the comma missing was a typo

Comment: Just cleaned up the output there. 

So does calling "BAR::T" append the info as you wanted?

Comment: it might, but in order to have the appended you would have to call BAR::T, which would not be usable because FOO::ABILITY has to be called.